# GOlang XML can't create a value and an attribute in one tag using xml.MarshalIndent

Tags: xml, go

New to Go and have got to create and xml file using xml.MarshalIndent from the "encoding/xml" package. One requirement is to create a tag like so:

`

```
   <Attributes>
      <Attribute name="Me">I really like this GO lang</Attribute>
      <Attribute name="problem">the xml package is not behaving</Attribute>
   </Attributes>
```

`

An array of tags with a value and an attribute, but no matter what I do (an i have tried lots a different ways), I just can not get it to work.

The code I wrote generates this:
`

```
<Attributes>
    <Attribute Name="J3K Solutions">
        <Attribute>IT Support</Attribute>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="stakoverflow">
        <Attribute>The place I go for help</Attribute>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

`

However I need it to look like this:
`

```
<Attributes>
    <Attribute Name="J3K Solutions" >IT Support</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="stakoverflow" >The place I go for help</Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

`
I've been reading the docs, and trying to get it working for hours now.
Anyone know if this is doable?

Code:

```
 package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type attributes struct {
    Name      string `xml:",attr"`
    Attribute string `xml:"Attribute"`
}

type fXML struct {
    MessageID string `xml:"MessageID,attr"`
    Timestamp string `xml:"timestamp,attr"`
    Version   string `xml:"version,attr"`
    Header    struct {
        From struct {
            Credential struct {
                Domain   string `xml:"domain,attr"`
                Identity string `xml:"Identity"`
            } `xml:"Credential"`
        } `xml:"From"`
        To struct {
            Credential struct {
                Domain   string `xml:"domain,attr"`
                Identity string `xml:"Identity"`
            } `xml:"Credential"`
        } `xml:"To"`
        Attributes struct {
            Attribute []attributes
        }
    } `xml:"Header"`
}

func main() {

rdata := &fXML{}
t := time.Now()
rdata.MessageID = "I'm really liken this GO language!"
rdata.Timestamp = t.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05")
rdata.Version = "1.0"
rdata.Header.From.Credential.Domain = "j3ksolutions.com"
rdata.Header.From.Credential.Identity = "J3K Solutions"
rdata.Header.To.Credential.Domain = "stackoverflow.com"
rdata.Header.To.Credential.Identity = "stackoverflow"
rdata.Header.Attributes.Attribute = append(rdata.Header.Attributes.Attribute,
    attributes{
        Name:      "J3K Solutions",
        Attribute: "IT Support and Custom Programing",
    })
rdata.Header.Attributes.Attribute = append(rdata.Header.Attributes.Attribute,
    attributes{
        Name:      "stakoverflow",
        Attribute: "The place I go for help",
    })

if m, err2 := xml.MarshalIndent(rdata, "", "\t"); err2 != nil {
    panic("xml.MarshalIndent FAILED: " + err2.Error())
} else {
    xmlheader := fmt.Sprintf("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n")
    m = append([]byte(xmlheader), m...)
    fmt.Printf("\n%s\n\n", m)
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use ",chardata" struct tag to write character data. Here is what [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) says

> - a field with tag ",chardata" is written as character data,   not as an XML element.

You may define the struct as follows

```
type attributes struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:Attribute"`
    Name      string   `xml:",attr"`
    Attribute string   `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

Here is play link : [go play](https://play.golang.org/p/bPklXJLqeF)

Comment: Thanks for for the quick response, chardata did the trick, in both cases, Sarathsp and Melvin. Shocked about the quick response, thanks again!

Comment: I answered first... Well, it's alright.. no worries.

Comment: I appreciate both answers, and actually tried to check both answers, but apparently can only check one answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set your Attribute Field to `xml:",chardata"`. See this: https://play.golang.org/p/NeTJW2iegw

```
type attributes struct {
    Name      string `xml:",attr"`
    Attribute string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

Hope this helps...